# Ionic build android error(Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-view

Everything was running fine and now this build error has started showing up suddenly:-

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   >     Could not download artifact 'bcprov-jdk15on.jar (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.48)'
>   >     Failed to download resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.48/bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.jar'.
>   >     Connection reset
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 2 mins 12.557 secs

Kindly help me in building this.

Comment: it's looks like java version issue.. can you check you ionic version and according to that a java compatible version and try again..

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with gradle.
Running command

> gradle init

solved the above error.